# NSTimer invalidate not working on stop button click

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am not able to stop timer on click of stop button but when i click on stop button it is firing again with less delay.

This is my ViewController.h File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
  NSTimer *timer;
}

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender;
@end
```

and ViewController.m File:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self      selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) timerFired{
    NSLog(@"Timer Fired");
}

- (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
}
@end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you correctly connected the button action to `stopTimer`? Is `stopTimer` being called?  It sounds like your stop button may be calling `startTimer` again

Comment: Yes u are right i have mistakenly connected stop timer button to start timer and stop timer methods both so i have resolve that thank u for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add :

```
- (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Also make startTimer call stopTimer first. before starting a new timer.

Comment: I have mistakenly connected stop timer button to start timer and stop timer methods both so i have resolve that thank u for help

Answer (score 0):

Check that `stopTimer` is actually being called. From your description it sounds like you have connected both buttons to `startTimer`.

It is a good idea to set timer to `nil` when you stop it and then you can check in `startTimer` to see if a timer is already running.